# Register variable to pre-existing list

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a list and a with_items loop where I go through a list. My question is when I go through the list how can I register/append the result to the existing list? I'm using Ansible version 2.0.1.0.

**My list:**

```
channels:
  channel1:
    item1: 'value'
    item2: 'value'
  channel2:
    item1: 'value'
    item2: 'value'
```

**The loop:**

```
- name: Do a shell command for each channel
  shell: some command that returns a number with the help {{ item }}
  with_items: "{{ channels }}"
  register: channels.item3.result #?? not sure how to do this
```

**What the output should be when doing a debug var=channels:**

```
channels:
  channel1:
    item1: 'value'
    item2: 'value'
    item3: 'result from shell command'
  channel2:
    item1: 'value'
    item2: 'value'
    item3: 'result from shell command'
```

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to update a dictionary in place but they're all going to be thwarted because Ansible (I believe) does not carry across changes to variables from task to task, except in the case of "set_fact" and, alas, you can't set_fact into a dictionary.

You'll need to create a Jinja2 filter that will set items deep into a dictionary. And then use 'register' on the task to capture the output, then a set_fact on 'channels' with the modified dictionary. Eg:

```
- set_fact:
    channels: "{{ channels|deep_set(item+'.item3', result) }}"
```

Within your definition for deep_set filter, something like this should work:

```
@environmentfilter
do_deep_set(environment, value, attr, val):
    parent = value
    parts = [int(x) if x.isdigit(x) else x for x in attr.split('.')]
    for part in parts:
        parent=environment.getitem(parent, part)
    parent[part[-1]] = val
    return value
```

I'm using environment.getitem just in case any part of the part is an attribute rather than an index/key. Setting *always* sets elements.